# What are the all Comment Tags Available in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, comments

Can someone please tell all Comment Tags Available in Android Studio ?

I am aware of only 2 as of now i.e TODO and FIXME.. anything else apart from these ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create more notes like TODO in Android Studio, for example CHECK or TEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373313/how-to-create-more-notes-like-todo-in-android-studio-for-example-check-or-test)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

default comment tags are TODO and FIXME 
but you can add more custom tag

check [this link(Defining TODO Patterns and Filters)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/defining-todo-patterns-and-filters.html)

> the content of the link (if it broke for some reason)

**Defining TODO Patterns and Filters**

TODO items in the source code are defined by a certain pattern.

Whenever a pattern is changed, or a new pattern is added, IntelliJ IDEA scans the whole project and rebuilds the index of TODO items. Results display in the TODO tool window, as described in the section Viewing TODO Items.

**By default**, IntelliJ IDEA provides two patterns:

```
\btodo\b.*

\bfixme\b.*
```

A generic pattern looks like `todo.*`

You might want to view the TODO comments of certain a type, and hide the others. For this purpose, IntelliJ IDEA suggests to use filters. This way you can show those items that match certain patterns only.

**To define a TODO pattern**

**1.** Open the TODO page of the Settings dialog.

**2.** In the Patterns section, click the Add button new to create a new pattern, or the Edit button edit1 to update an existing one. The Add/Edit Pattern dialog opens.

**3.** In the Pattern field, enter the regular expression that describes the desired pattern.

**4.** In the Icon list, select the desired icon that will mark the matching TODO items in the TODO tool window.

**5.** Specify the color and font properties, which IntelliJ IDEA will use to highlight the matching comments in the source code.

**6.** Select the Case sensitive checkbox, if you want the pattern to be case-sensitive.

**To define a filter that will be used to show specific types of TODO items**

**1.** Open the TODO page of the Settings dialog.

**2.** In the Filters section, click click the Add button [image: add] to create a new filter, or the Edit button [image: edit1] to update an existing one.

**3.** In the Add/Edit Filter dialog, specify the filter name, and select the patterns to be included in the filter.

Comment: @AnudeepAnanth accept as correct answer if it helped you